# Virtual live migration and running I/O?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization, hyper-v

In order to perform VM memory migration, usually one of two techniques is applied, Pre-copy memory migration, and Post-copy memory migration.

I've read a bunch about it but wasn't able to find how the I/O is handled. Assuming that you have issued read command on a large file (one that is not in the memory) and started the migration, what will happen when the OS issues interrupt saying that the read is complete? How will the destination machine know that there's been change made?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general, a VMM will not migrate a VM that has direct access to any devices. So the I/O in progress is being handled by a virtual device instance within the VMM. When the VMM migrates the state of the VM to another physical system, the state of the virtual device instance is migrated as well. When the VM is resumed, the virtual device is also resumed with the same state that it had on the source machine, and the I/O completes as if the migration had not occurred.

Comment: Many thanks for clarification! What does happen to the physical devices such as keyboard, or even CD drive? where is the newly read information written to? Is the physical address of the device passed to the destination machine?

Comment: The guest only sees a virtual keyboard. The physical keyboard belongs to the host. The same is usually true for disks, CD drives, etc. When the VM is migrated, the virtual device on the new machine connects to the physical device on the new machine. The guest still sees the same virtual device, which was migrated along with the VM. Although there are ways to give a guest physical access to such devices, such a guest would typically not be migratable.